# PDF file is not getting attach to mail composer

Tags: objective-c, email, pdf

I am creating a pdf file to be attach to an email with the **MFMailComposeViewController** but I'm checking the file before doing the attach and is empty (nil) which of course nothing gets sent with the email.

I don't know whats wrong, because I'm following step by step what I have seen in here and other pages, but still not working.

I'm missing something that obviously I'm not seen..

This is the mail send function..

```
- (IBAction)emailSend:(UIButton *)sender {

    // calling pdf file creator
    [self drawText];

    // Email message implementation
    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = myMssgSubject.text;

    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<h3>%@</h3>\n<h4>iReceipt Number: %@</h4>\n<h4>Customer: %@</h4>\n<h4>Customer Address: %@</h4>\n<h4>Customer Phone: %@</h4>", myMssgText.text, myReceiptNo, myCustomer, myCusAddress, myCusPhoneNo]; // Change the message body to HTML

    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:myMssgReceiver.text];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailViewController setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:YES];
    [mailViewController setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"invoice" ofType:@"pdf"]];

    if(pdfData == nil)
        NSLog(@"Its empty!");

    // for .doc is application/msword and for .docx is application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
    [mailViewController addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

I have use all these forms to get file path and type to then attach it to my email composer...

```
// Attach a pdf to the email
//NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"invoce" ofType:@"pdf"];

//NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

//NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:pdfFileName]];
//[mailView addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"invoce"];

// Get the resource path and read the file using NSData
//NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:extension];
//NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

//NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
//UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bounds, nil);
```

Then, this is my function to create the pdf file which I'm using [**this example/tutorial**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1)

```
-(void)drawText
{
    fileName = @"Invoice.PDF"; // NSString

    // NSArray
    arrayPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                        NSDocumentDirectory,
                                        NSUserDomainMask,
                                        YES);

    // NSString
    path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // NSString
    pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSString* textToDraw = @"Hello World";
    CFStringRef stringRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)textToDraw;

    // Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter.
    CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, NULL);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);

    CGRect frameRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50);
    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

    // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);

    // Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);

    // Mark the beginning of a new page.
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

    // Get the graphics context.
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
    // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
    // the current transform prior to drawing.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 100);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Draw the frame.
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(stringRef);
    CFRelease(framesetter);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

}
```

Not sure if you guys need more explanation or information, please let me know and I will comment or provided within the post..

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119524/pdf-and-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: I tried that before but it wasnt working, I guess something was missing, but now it is.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your drawText() method is creating file with text "hello world" inside documents folder.
to manually check this out you can finds a path to this file, try this lines of code to logs this path.

```
NSString *appFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSLog(@"App Directory is: %@", appFolderPath);
```

So if you cannot approximately put this file and attach to email, it's second question . And all works!

```
NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Invoice.pdf"];
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
```

Comment: Sorry, I really dont get what you are trying to do.. where paths is coming from?? fileManager is never used either..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119524/pdf-and-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller) which help me to fix the problem..

In other words, this what I did within my **emailSend** function..

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

NSString* fileName = @"invoice.pdf";

NSArray *arrayPaths =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                    NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                    YES);

NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];

[mailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"invoice.pdf"];
```

Thanks for the help :)